# Modbus read timeout error for JlibModbus Java Library

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, modbus

I am using [jlibmodbus-1.2.8.4](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jlibmodbus/) Java Modbud Library for implementing Java 8 Application on `Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`

And for serial communication I am using JSSC - Java Simple Serial Connector.

I am using `USB to Serial Converter` cable for serial connection to my machine. 
I have used FTDI Drivers for my ubuntu as the converter cable that I am using is not providing Ubuntu drivers. So I have installed [FTDI drivers](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm) for x86.

I have test application and it did worked for the first time perfectly and I am able to read/write registers with test MODBUS simulator. But after reboot I got serial read time out error and it had stopped working.

**I have below questions:**

1. Do I need to use USB to Serial Converter FTDI Drivers? or Ubuntu 14.04 LTS does not require it and it has built in support.
2. I have also did load usbserial module using `sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0xXXXXX product=0xXXXXX` do I need to do it, also added it in `/etc/modules`?
3. In the latest release of "JlibModbus" `1.2.9.0` I get CRC check error and not the serial read time out error as previous version? I have verified Parity and Baud rate and no issue in these parameters but still CRC for reading Holding register fails?
4. Is there any other options of MODBUS RTU Master Java based Library? I have seen jamod and modbus4j but looks like then don't support RTU Master and I don't find any sample.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the latest (1.2.9.1) of the JLibModbus library with a USB-to-Serial Converter. I'm using Moxa UPort 1150I and a Noname USB-to-RS485 converter.

Please turn the DEBUG mode on and show output.

Also, you can try using the j2mod library.